# Papers and Books about Numerical methods for nonlinear PDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, parabolic-pde

Actually, I am intersecting in the filed of numerical solution of nonlinear PDEs. I am trying to improve some numerical scheme to solve high order equations. Could anyone mention me some recent papers and books dealing with numerical schemes (such as FDM, FED, KSS) and relation between them. Thanks

Comment: FED= Fast explicit Diffusion KSS=Krylov Subspace Spectral

Comment: I am trying to solve a nonlinear fourth order degenerate PDE